# Could not use variable assigned from variable registred from pause

Tags: ansible

I'm using conditions in Ansible, and I have used the `pause` module to prompt for a variable, but I m not being able to use that variable for my remaining task. I wanted to change the DNS Server IP according to  the value inserted from the end-user, but it didn't work.

Code:

```yaml
 - name: os system
   pause:
    prompt: |
     Which os do you want to use?
      1- Windows Server
      2- CentOS_7
      3- CentOs_8
      4- Ubuntu
      5- Others
   register: os_system
 - name: Rename_PC
   pause:
    prompt: Enter New PC Name
   register: rename
   when: os_system.user_input == "1"
 - name: Domain Decision
   pause:
    prompt: Do you want your PC in Domain
   register: decision
   when: os_system.user_input == "1"
 - name: Domain Name
   pause:
     prompt: Enter Domain Name
   register: dc_name
   when: os_system.user_input == "1" and decision.user_input == "yes"
 - name: DNS IP
   pause:
     prompt: Enter DNS IP
   register: d_ip
   when: os_system.user_input == "1"  and decision.user_input "yes"
 - name: Domain DNS
   vmware_vm_shell:
    hostname: "{{ vc_name }}"
    username: "{{ myuser }}"
    password: "{{ mypass }}"
    validate_certs: no
    vm_username: Administrator
    vm_password: '{{ guest_password}}'
    vm_id: "{{ guest_name  }}"
    vm_shell: 'c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
    vm_shell_args:  '-command "(Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -ServerAddress {{ d_ip }})"'
    wait_for_process: yes
   when: os_system.user_input == "1" and decision.user_input | bool
   delegate_to: localhost
```

As you can see I have entered the DNS ip as `d_ip` in *Enter DNS IP*, but down below when I tried to use `{{ d_ip }}` it didn't change the DNS IP, that I have enetered above when the prompt was being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the fact that the return from `pause` [is a dictionary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pause_module.html#return-values) and that the user input is stored in the `user_input` field.

So your fix is just to use `d_ip.user_input` instead of simply `d_ip`:

```yaml
vm_shell_args: '-command "(Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -ServerAddress {{ d_ip.user_input }})"'
```

---

Mind that it is just the same behaviour as you already used on the `when` condition above, where you are indeed using the `user_input` field:

```yaml
when: os_system.user_input == "1"
```